# How can I register given info on signup page by user to Firestore directly?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm building an App with a detailed Sign up page that requesting name, nationality and phone number from the new user.

I want to register all the provided information above to the newly created user ID who just signed up now.

I did google search for the method but all what I found is how to feed data to user.uid after signing in ... Ok that is very simple and easy to retrieve the user ID after signing in by Auth.auth().didChangeListner

But what I want exactly is how to feed given information from user directly to his new created ID?
Or how to get the latest created user ID without Singing in?

Comment: how did you create the user id if you didn't sign him in?

Comment: You can use the admin SDK to list all users, https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users

Answer (score 1):

The typical process is:

1. You create the user account on Firebase Authentication.
2. You then write the additional registration information to the database.

Something like:

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
    if let eror = error {
        print(eror.localizedDescription )
    } else {
        // user created successfully
        print(result.user.uid)
        // TODO: register their additional information in the database under their UID
    }
}
```

Comment: no this done already my friend... user created from the App signup page as per your method above... but I need to feed the given information by user in the sign up page to his user ID in firestore!

Comment: If you've done this already, edit your question to show the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will maximize the chances that someone can help.